# ApplIdentity data set on the MQ message is not read by the reciever

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am using TIBCO Business works so I can't directly us JMS API and I can only set the input to the API. Below is the MQ queue URI I have created but I get an error when the application tries to get handle to queue during runtime.

```
queue://QManager/QName?targetClient=1&mdWriteEnabled=true&mdMessageContext=1
```

Error I am getting

```
caused by: com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSExceptionWrapper: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0005: The specified value '??1' is not allowed for 'mdMessageContext'.
The given value is not allowed for the property specified.
Change the value to a value that is supported for the property.
```

According to IBM knowledge article, the value I am setting for mdMessageContext is correct. below are the links to the Knowledge article.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032350_.htm

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/constant-values.html#com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.CommonConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you really have a `;` before `mdWriteEnabled=true`?

Comment: oh sorry no, that was copy past error; pls ignore

Comment: The ?? before the 1 in your error message looks strange. And just targetClient=1 works fine ? Try for example with targetClient=99 and no mdMessageContext and see if you also get an error with that '??" in front. Maybe there's something else going on... (BW replacing things with 'MessageContext')